# Removing CMOV Instructions using GCC-9.2.0 (x86)

Tags: gcc, g++, x86-64, branch-prediction

I am looking to compile a set of benchmark suites using traditional GCC optimizations (as in using -O2/3) and comparing this with the same benchmark using no cmov instructions. I have seen several posts/websites addressing this issue (all from several years ago and therefore referencing an older version of GCC than 9.2.0). Essentially, the answers from these was to use the following four flags ([this](https://github.com/xiadz/cmov) is a good summary of everything I've found online):

```
-fno-if-conversion -fno-if-conversion2 -fno-tree-loop-if-convert -fno-tree-loop-if-convert-stores
```

Following this advice, I am using the following command to compile my benchmarks (theoretically with no cmov instructions).

```
g++-9.2.0 -std=c++11 -O2 -g -fno-if-conversion -fno-if-conversion2 -fno-tree-loop-if-convert -fno-tree-loop-if-convert-stores -fno-inline *.C -o bfs-nocmov
```

However, I am still finding instances where cmov is being used. If I change the optimization flag to `-O0` the cmov instructions are not generated, so I am assuming there must be someway to disable this in GCC without modifying the c code/assembly.

Below is a code snippet example of what I am trying to disable (the last instruction is the cmov I am looking to avoid):

```
  int mx = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
  41bc8a:   45 85 e4                test   %r12d,%r12d
  41bc8d:   7e 71                   jle    41bd00 <_Z11suffixArrayPhi+0xe0>
  41bc8f:   41 8d 44 24 ff          lea    -0x1(%r12),%eax
  41bc94:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
.../suffix/src/ks.C:92
  int mx = 0;
  41bc97:   31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
  41bc99:   48 8d 54 03 01          lea    0x1(%rbx,%rax,1),%rdx
  41bc9e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
.../suffix/src/ks.C:94
    if (s[i] > mx) mx = s[i];
  41bca0:   44 0f b6 07             movzbl (%rdi),%r8d
  41bca4:   44 39 c1                cmp    %r8d,%ecx
  41bca7:   41 0f 4c c8             cmovl  %r8d,%ecx
```

Finally, here is the code snippet generated by using `-O0`. I cannot use any optimization level lower than `-O2`, and while manually manipulating the code is an option I have a lot of benchmarks I am using so I would like to find a general solution.

```
  for (int i=0; i < n; i++) 
 c67:   8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
 c6a:   3b 45 d4                cmp    -0x2c(%rbp),%eax
 c6d:   7d 34                   jge    ca3 <_Z11suffixArrayPhi+0x105>
.../suffix/src/ks.C:94
    if (s[i] > mx) mx = s[i];
 c6f:   8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
 c72:   48 63 d0                movslq %eax,%rdx
 c75:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
 c79:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
 c7c:   0f b6 00                movzbl (%rax),%eax
 c7f:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
 c82:   39 45 e4                cmp    %eax,-0x1c(%rbp)
 c85:   7d 16                   jge    c9d <_Z11suffixArrayPhi+0xff>
.../suffix/src/ks.C:94 (discriminator 1)
 c87:   8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
 c8a:   48 63 d0                movslq %eax,%rdx
 c8d:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
 c91:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
 c94:   0f b6 00                movzbl (%rax),%eax
 c97:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
 c9a:   89 45 e4                mov    %eax,-0x1c(%rbp)
```

If somebody has any advice or direction to look in, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: For 32-bit code (`-m32`) you could use `-march=pentium -mtune=skylake` ; CMOV was new with P6, not supported by P5 Pentium.  But then you're stuck with 32-bit code with its legacy stack-args calling convention and half the registers.  `-march=pentium` can't be used for 64-bit code, and CMOV is baseline for x86-64.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not very familiar with how gcc works (or at all) but after some more research I came across [Tree SSA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Tree-SSA-passes.html) and [RTL](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL-passes.html#RTL-passes) passes which deal with if-conversion. By using the flags -fdisable-tree-phiopt[1-4] and -fdisable-rtl-ce[1-3] in addition to the previously mentioned flags, it seems I was able to stop cmov instructions from generating in most cases.

Comment: I don't know GCC internals super well, like which pass does exactly what.  Those passes might also include other important optimizations, so it might not be a fair comparison if you want to actually benchmark the resulting code.  If you modified the GCC source code, you might be able to build a version that didn't know about CMOV for x86-64 but could still do other optimizations.  That might be closer to fair, although there might be some GCC tuning heuristics that were tuned with the assumption that CMOV is possible.  Or maybe nothing significant, IDK.